# I deleted Elasticsearch folder in /etc within AWS EC2, how to restore back?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I have built the Flask application which is linked to Elasticsearch(port:9200), Now I need to deploy this application withing AWS EC2, however while performing I deleted the Elasticsearch folder within /etc and now I am unable to start the Elasticsearch.

Please let me know how to restore the deleted folder ?

Comment: Since EC2 is (most of the time at least) just a linux machine, have you tried this?   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files